# HCatalog Issue while installing Oozie

Tags: ubuntu, oozie

While trying to install oozie, I run the command

```
./mkdistro.sh -DskipTests
```

but 6th out of 25th build fails with the following output:

[Log Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdZrg.jpg)

[Log Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ9E2.png)

How do I solve this error? Is it related to Hive? Does anything need to be updated in pm.xml file? (I have tried updating hive version in pom.xml)

I have tried updating Hive version in pom.xml

Comment: for anybody else that runs into this problem, the fix is to override the conjars repo in pom.xml
<code><repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>conjars</id>
    <url>https://conjars.wensel.net/repo/</url>
  </repository>
....`